# Set notification for specific date and time in kotlin newbie

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to set notification for a specific date and time (ex: 15/02/2021 02:00:00) in android

Can anyone help me i am newbie?

Comment: fyi i use xiaomi for testing, android pie :O, i am newbie and need help tutorial , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule notifications using AlarmManager.

Also check this:
Beginning with API 19 (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

Comment: can u give me example mom? i am newbie :(